# Запись бинарного представления файла в строку и обратно в файл

Tags: c#, binary, binary-file

Как можно файл представить в бинарном виде? Например есть какая-нибудь картинка, представим мы в программе выбираем ее с помощью класса `File`, как в строке которую мы объявили присвоить ту же картинку только в двоичном виде.

Comment: Опишите подробней вопрос.

Comment: Вам повезло! Все файлы и так в "бинарном виде".

Comment: @ГеннадийП Обновил

Comment: @Igor Как мне увидеть этот "бинарный вид" в программе, в `string`?

Comment: Предположим, есть файл `test.txt`, в котором одна строчка `abcd`. Что Вы должны увидеть в "бинарном виде"?

Comment: Попробую телепатировать что же имелось в виду под "бинарным видом": ```String bin = String.Join("", File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\test\file.png").Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToArray());```

Comment: @gregzakharov отлично! То что надо можете оформить как ответ пожалуйста, только если не сложно, напишите как наоборот, имея 0 и 1 перевести в файл, зная его расширение.

Comment: @Log1c0 Вопрос: Зачем все это все? Если для передачи данных по текстовому каналу, то есть проверенный временем `Base64` для конвертации Bin<->Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить бинарное представление в виде строки:

```
String bin = String.Join("", File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\path\file.png").Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).ToArray());
```

Записать данное представление обратно в файл:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\path\file.png", Enumerable.Range(0, bin.Length / 8).Select(x => (Byte)Convert.ToInt32(bin.Substring(x * 8, 8), 2)).ToArray());
```